# Running SSH on AWS EC2 instance on port other than 22 but for Centos

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to open another port for SSH (443) on AMI CentOS, but without success. I found a script for Ubuntu made by "gugol", which worked perfectly for Ubuntu, but have not managed to make it work on CentOS.

The script is

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
perl -pi -e 's/^#?Port 22$/Port 443/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
service sshd restart || service ssh restart
```

Comment: Did you check this steps http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-change-ssh-port/ Remember you have to open the port in Centos Firewall also and AWS security group firewall also

Answer (score 0):

First, look at the security groups for the server and check that port 443 is allowed on the EC2 see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#describing-security-group

Next on the server check that port 443 isn't being used by another service.  As root on the server do

```
ss -ln |grep 443
```

There should be no LISTEN lines listed.  No output at all is good

On Centos the Port isn't declared explictly in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config but there is a commented line of it

Find the commented line, remove the # at the start, alter the port to 443

Then, as root issue a "service sshd restart"